# How to log a talend job result?

Tags: talend

We have many talend jobs to transfer data from oracle (tOracleInput) to redshift (tRedshiftOutputBulkExec). I would like to store the result information into a DB table. For example:
Job name, start time, running time, rows loaded, successful or failed

I know if I turn on log4j, most those information can be derived from the log. However, saving it into DB table will make it easy to check and report the result.

I'm most interested in records loaded. I checked this link http://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-logs-and-errors-component-reference.html and manual of tRedshiftOutputBulkExec. None of them gives me such information.

Will Talend Administration Center provide such function? What is the best way to implement it?

Thanks,

Comment: Was the answer below sufficient?  If so, please upvote.  If not, please let me know how I can help you further.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the URL you provided, tLogCatcher should provide you with what you need (minus the rows loaded, which you can get with a lookup).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I started with Talend Studio Version 6.4.1. There you can set "Stats & Logs" for a job. It can log to console, files or database. When writing to a DB you set JDBC parameters and the name for three tables:

- Stats Table: stores start and end timestamps of the job
- Logs Table: stores error messages
- Meter Table: stores the count of rows for each monitored flow

They correspond to the components tStatCatcher, tLogCatcher, tFlowMeterCatcher, where you can find the needed table schema.

To make a flow monitored select it, open tab "Component" and mark the checkbox "Monitor this connection".

To see the logged values you can use the "AMC" (Active Monitoring Console) in Studio or TAC.